# BVH Importer/Parser for XNA

Tags: xna

Is there a BVH importer/parser for XNA?  Does anyone know of any tutorials/source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used it myself, but according to the codeplex site, the XNA Animation Component supports it:
http://animationcomponents.codeplex.com/

> Works on fbx, x, asf/amc, and **bvh** formats

Comment: I found this, but it's not been updated since 2007, so I'm a little unsure how easy it will be to convert.